# File Writing through C program

Tags: linux

When we open a file using fopen() in C(Ubuntu platform and gcc compiler) and write to it,does the content is directly written to the hard disk address where the file resides or is it first brought into primary memory?
What is the actual process with which a file could be written or read from its location in hard disk through a C program in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The C library does not make the actual write to disk. It is the job of operating system. C library will make a system call to kernel to write it to the disk. It may even implement a buffer to minimize the number of system calls. And kernel also implement buffer to optimize real writing to disk. In general when you are working with C you don't think this much low level. However, you need to ensure that you have closed the file correctly. The actual disk management is the job of OS.

[The Design of the UNIX Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) by Maurice J. Bach contains nice explanation of Unix kernel. You may have a look as a beginning.

Comment: So how does the system call write() which is responsible for writing to a file performs the write operation,does it write directly to hard disk or what is the actual process.I have doubt whether the kernel system call code could write directly to hard disk address or not?

Comment: I am afraid that the answer will vary from kernel to kernel, from disk to disk and I am not that much expert on this field. The basic idea is kernel will use memory buffer, i.e. write() won't write in the disk at once. This buffer will be flushed to the disk when kernel decides that it is optimal to write. Every disk is associated with a disk controller, which may even have their own buffer. Kernel, disk controller try to optimize things like reducing number of actual writes, minimize the movement of disk head etc.

Comment: After a few Googling I have found this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-filesystem/. Check High-level architecture section closely. This may clarify few things that you are searching.

Answer (score 1):

Under UNIX-like systems, generally, there are two levels of caching when writing information to a file on disk.

The first is in the C run time libraries, where it's likely to be buffered (unless you turn off buffering in some manner). You can use a C call like `fflush` to flush these buffers.

The second is at the operating system level, where buffers are held, before being written to the physical disk. A call to `fsync` can force these buffers to be flushed to disk.